# Java Fibonacci for loop variable

Tags: java

This is a program which takes a command line variable, parses it into an int and the output is the fibonacci number equal to that cmd line argument. So if i enter 7, the output will be 13.  since: 1 1 2 3 5 8 13
Can someone explain the b = a; inside the for loop? Since they're both already equal to 1, why do they need to be set equal to eachother?

```
    int a,b,c;
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    c = 0;
    if (n == 1 || n == 2)

        System.out.println(1);

    else 
    {
        for (int i = 3; i<=n; i++)
        {
            c = a + b;
            b = a;
            a = c;
        }
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: They're equal the first time yes, but have a look at what happens if the loop keeps running

Comment: Because `a` and `b` need to move one step forward each iteration to get the next `c`.

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` are equal to 1 *initially*, so on the first iteration of the loop, this statement does nothing. But let's look at what happens on later iterations:

```java
Initial state:
a = 1
b = 1
c = 0
Iteration 1:
c = 1 + 1 = 2
b = a = 1
a = c = 2
Iteration 2:
c = 1 + 2 = 3
b = a = 2
a = c = 3
Iteration 3:
c = 2 + 3 = 5
b = a = 3
a = c = 5
```

Essentially, `a` stores the previous number in the sequence, while `b` stores the second to last. Since the first 2 numbers of the sequence are `1, 1`, `b` will stay as 1 for two iterations, but then change later on.

Answer (score 0):

`Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2`, i.e. for starting from `a = 1` and `b = 1`, you have to calculate next fibonacci number and move `a` and `b` to the one position right.

```
public static long fibonacci(int n) {
    n = Math.abs(n);

    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    if (n < 3)
        return 1;

    long a = 1;
    long b = 1;
    long c = 0;

    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        c = a + b;
        b = a;
        a = c;
    }

    return c;
}
```